# Join Query in Oracle Xpress Edition

Tags: inner-join, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

Hello I am creating a table with name `Category`, inserted two rows.

When I am joining this table, output printed multiple rows.

My Table is:- Category

```
CREATE TABLE Category(
       ID int NOT NULL Primary key, 
       Code varchar(50), 
       Name varchar(200), 
       Notes varchar(500),
       Image1 varchar(250),
       Image2 varchar(250), 
       Image3 varchar(250), 
       CreatedBy int NOT NULL, 
       PageTitle varchar(100), 
       MetaName varchar(200),
       MetaDescription varchar(500), 
       MetaKeywords varchar(500),
       ERPReferencesSysteID int, 
       ERPReferencesID int,
       AssignedTo int,
       Status int );
```

Insert Query:-

```
insert into Category values (902,'Code2', 'NAME2','Note2', 'Image12', 
  'Image22','Image32', 2016, 'PageTitle2','MetaName2', 'MetaDescription2', 
  'MetaKeyword2',02, 08, 2,1);
```

My Join Query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT info.COLUMN_NAME AS NAME, info.OWNER AS TABLESCHEMA,
 info.TABLE_NAME,UIC.COLUMN_POSITION AS POSITION,info.NULLABLE AS ISNULLABLE,
 info.DATA_TYPE AS DATATYPE,tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE AS CONSTRAINTTYPE, 
 tc.R_OWNER AS REFERENCESCHEMA FROM all_tab_columns  
 info join  all_constraints  tc on info.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME 
 join user_cons_columns rk on info.TABLE_NAME = rk.TABLE_NAME 
 join USER_IND_COLUMNS UIC on UIC.TABLE_NAME = info.TABLE_NAME 
 where info.TABLE_NAME= 'CATEGORY' AND info.owner ='SAN' ORDER BY 
 UIC.COLUMN_POSITION ASC;
```

When I am executing this join query rows are showing multiple times.

What i am doing wrong in this query?

Comment: It helps to show the output you expect and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN`'s for joining your tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT info.COLUMN_NAME AS NAME, info.OWNER AS TABLESCHEMA,
info.TABLE_NAME,UIC.COLUMN_POSITION AS POSITION,info.NULLABLE AS ISNULLABLE,
info.DATA_TYPE AS DATATYPE,tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE AS CONSTRAINTTYPE, 
tc.R_OWNER AS REFERENCESCHEMA 
FROM all_tab_columns info 
INNER JOIN  all_constraints  tc ON info.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME 
INNER JOIN user_cons_columns rk ON info.TABLE_NAME = rk.TABLE_NAME 
INNER JOIN USER_IND_COLUMNS UIC ON UIC.TABLE_NAME = info.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE info.TABLE_NAME = 'CATEGORY' 
AND info.owner ='SAN' 
ORDER BY UIC.COLUMN_POSITION ASC;
```

Comment: They are all inner joins; that's the default. (In Oracle anyway)

Comment: @AlexPoole  Then what is the solution for that.?

Answer (score 0):

You have three constraints in the table; the primary key and two not-null constraints. One of those is redundant as the primary key column is implicitly not null anyway.

So there are three rows in `user_cons_columns`. Two of those are for `id`.

```
SELECT uc.constraint_name, uc.constraint_type, ucc.column_name
FROM user_constraints uc
JOIN user_cons_columns ucc ON ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
WHERE uc.table_name = 'CATEGORY';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C COLUMN_NAME        
------------------------------ - --------------------
SYS_C00110620                  C ID                  
SYS_C00110621                  C CREATEDBY           
SYS_C00110622                  P ID
```

There is also one row in `user_ind_columns` for `id`, but not one for `createdby`, which is the other not-null constraint.

```
SELECT ui.index_name, uic.column_name
FROM user_indexes ui
JOIN user_ind_columns uic ON uic.index_name = ui.index_name
WHERE ui.table_name = 'CATEGORY';

INDEX_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME        
------------------------------ --------------------
SYS_C00110622                  ID
```

Both the `id` rows in `user_cons_columns` are matching with the one in `user_ind_columns`, so you get two rows in the result set. The `distinct` isn't helping because you are including the constraint type in the result set, so you see separate rows for P and C.

You are also not including the `column_name` in the joins; so all 16 row in `all_tab_columns` are joining to all three constraints and their columns. As you are using inner joins you seem to only want to show the primary key and its index, so this seems to be a long-winded way to do that:

```
SELECT distinct atc.column_name AS NAME, atc.owner AS tableschema,
 atc.table_name, aic.column_position AS position, atc.nullable AS isnullable,
 atc.data_type AS datatype, ac.constraint_type AS constrainttype, 
 ac.r_owner AS referenceschema
FROM all_tab_columns atc
JOIN all_constraints ac
ON ac.owner = atc.owner
AND ac.table_name = atc.table_name 
JOIN all_cons_columns acc
ON acc.table_name = atc.table_name 
AND acc.column_name = atc.column_name
JOIN all_ind_columns aic
ON aic.table_owner = atc.owner
AND aic.table_name = atc.table_name 
AND aic.column_name = atc.column_name
WHERE atc.table_name= 'CATEGORY'
AND atc.owner = 'SAN'
AND ac.constraint_type = 'P'
ORDER BY aic.column_position ASC;
```

Which gets a single row for the P constraint ID column. If you intended to show all the columns you'd need outer joins.

Comment: :- I Have tried with query.. but still problem is there. Now 3 row having same column name showing.